# Why is their a limit on max number of clauses in bool query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know that why there is a limit on max clauses in a bool query that is **1024**
**indices.query.bool.max_clause_count : 1024**.

Also is it ok if an OR query is fired with say **1 million terms** in a bool query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***max_clause_count*** setting isn't specific to elasticsearch. Its a static lucene setting hence can only be setup in config file.

I think this limit is set for safeguarding your search where by passing gigantic query can easily DOS your server. By upping the limit you understand the consequences and accept the performance implications.

The right limit also seems to be debated in the Lucene community itself when you look at their [discussions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4835). In the discussion they are even comfortable to change the allowed number to ***Integer.MAX_VALUE*** but again larger numbers can impact performance.

These queries will probably be slower, but it also depends on the kind of data you have. Also profile for eviction in filter caches. In our usecase we are querying for average 50,000 clauses and haven't seen much performance effect as the nature of clauses is very dense.

Answer (score 2):

***indices.query.bool.max_clause_count***   setting is a protection against abusive queries with many search terms. The limits are there for a reason If there are many clauses which will lead to many lookups and disk seek, which in turn slows down your searches.

Below link might help you and explain it more deeply

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/increase-query-performance-for-many-or-clauses/63425/3